# Searching matches columns in 2 df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 df, and I want change value in df1, if it has two matching values in df2

| campaign_name | adgroup_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple_campaign | apple_1 | paused |
| apple_campaign | apple_2 | paused |
| apple_campaign | apple_3 | paused |
| pear_campaign | pear_1 | paused |
| pear_campaign | pear_2 | paused |
| pear_campaign | pear_3 | paused |
| pear_campaign | pear_4 | paused |
| peach_campaign | peach_1 | paused |
| peach_campaign | peach_2 | paused |

| campaign_name | adgroup_name | headline | others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple_campaign | apple_1 | apple chips | etc |
| apple_campaign | apple_1 | apple cake | etc |
| apple_campaign | apple_3 | apple juice | etc |
| pear_campaign | pear_1 | pear chips | etc |
| pear_campaign | pear_2 | pear cake | etc |
| pear_campaign | pear_4 | pear juice | etc |
| pear_campaign | pear_4 | pear pumpkin | etc |

So, I want to set "**Status**"->**enabled**, if df2 has the same "**campaign_name**", and "**adgroup_name**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `merge` with indicator and identify the merged rows:

```
df1.loc[(df1
 .merge(df2, on=['campaign_name', 'adgroup_name'], how='left', indicator=True)
 ['_merge'].eq('both')
), 'status'] = 'enabled'
```

output:

```
    campaign_name adgroup_name   status
0  apple_campaign      apple_1  enabled
1  apple_campaign      apple_2  enabled
2  apple_campaign      apple_3   paused
3   pear_campaign       pear_1  enabled
4   pear_campaign       pear_2  enabled
5   pear_campaign       pear_3  enabled
6   pear_campaign       pear_4   paused
7  peach_campaign      peach_1  enabled
8  peach_campaign      peach_2  enabled
```